# Duplicate entry cause mysql deadlock

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I use flask with flask-sqlalchemy to record app user increment for statistics, I got this error:

```
(_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry '2017-2' for key 'uq_weekstatistics_year_week'") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO week_statistics (year, week, count) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: (2017, 2, 1)]
```

here is my model:

```
class WeekStatistics(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'week_statistics'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
year = db.Column(db.Integer, default=int(datetime.now().strftime('%Y')), nullable=False)
week = db.Column(db.Integer, default=int(datetime.now().strftime('%W')), nullable=False)
count = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)

__table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint(''year', 'week',
                                      name='uq_weekstatistics_year_week'), )
```

and here is code in api:

```
week_statistics = WeekStatistics.query.with_lockmode("update").\
        filter_by(year=int(datetime.now().strftime('%Y')),
                  week=int(datetime.now().strftime('%W'))).first()
if week_statistics is None:
    week_statistics = WeekStatistics()
    week_statistics.count = 1
else:
    week_statistics.count += 1
try:
    db.session.add(week_statistics)
    db.session.commit()
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
   db.session.rollback()
```

mysql: 5.6, innodb engine, RR isolation level.

if there is no such record in my database, this error would occurs, and my databases would get and deadlock, if there exists such a record, it works well.

in my opinion when in concurrency conditions, multiple transactions begins and insert the same record, only one transaction can commit the insertion and the others would rollback. But why there comes a deadlock and this deadlock cause all my db query and update fails.

Comment: as you have specified `Primary key for year` its throwing above error. Please drop the `PK index`

Comment: year is not Primary key， i just add a unique index on year and week

Comment: so you need toi drop that index so that you can insert duplicate value

Comment: I do not want to insert duplicate value, so I add that constraint。